# I'm trying to add a function to move my scene camera when it is scrolled in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, dom-events, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to add a function to move my scene camera when it is scrolled in React, but since I just started using the library recently, I am not quite sure which implementation to use, here's what I'm thinking of trying:

```js
function moveCamera() {
   const top = document.getBoundingClientRect().top;
   camera.position.z = top * -0.001;
   camera.position.x = top * -0.0001;
   camera.position.y = top * -0.0001;
}

document.body.onscroll = moveCamera;
```

So, now I know this is the implementation with regular Vanilla JS, I was just wondering how I would do the same thing in react, or is it just the same thing?

Comment: Reactjs is only a library, if it's run on Browser, you are free to select just like Vanilajs

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, i will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tying-canvas-to-scroll-offset-itfgk but there are many ways to do it. generally i would suggest you use r3f when you want to use threejs in react. otherwise these two worlds are separate and will be much harder to unify.